# VueRouter throws an undefined error only on mobile when routing with $router.push({ ... })

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a login that waits for user to be authenticated before routing. When the user is authenticated, I throw an event that is caught in the Login component and then I execute this code :

```js
EventBus.$on('userConnected', (user) =>{
    let routeName = isRoleGreaterOrEqual(user.role, 'superadmin') ? 'admin' : 'draw';
    this.$router.push({"name" : routeName}).catch(e => {
       console.log(e);
    });
});
```

The console.log(e) here will show 'undefined' in chrome's console.
Here's how I throw the event after querying some stuff in firebase firestore:

```js
usersCollection.where("email", "==", email).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let user = doc.data();
    anotherCollection.doc(user.email).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      let someDatas = querySnapshot.data();
      if (someDatas) {
        commit(types.MUTATE_LOAD_MORE_DATA, someDatas);
      }
      commit(types.MUTATE_LOAD_USER, user);
      EventBus.$emit('userConnected', user);
    });
  })
}).catch((e) => {
  //handle error
});
```

The error is only thrown when I'm on mobile (chrome devtools mobile). The only thing I could find is that I can silence the error with the .catch, but I'm not satisfied with only silencing it, I'd like to know why it's thrown in the first place, especially since it's an 'undefined' error so it's really unclear to me.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: 'undefined' is the actual message when I console.log(e) inside the catch

Comment: I can't see that code anywhere in your question

Comment: where I wrote '//this catch silences the error', if I console.log(e), console will show 'undefined'